# How can i color the text of a specific item in a specific case in listBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method:

```
private void batch_Resize(Image sourceImage,string oldfName, string sourceDirectory,string oldFileName)
        {
            Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                gr.DrawImage(sourceImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height));
                i = i + 1;
                newImage.Save(@"d:\NewImages1\" + i.ToString("D6") + ".gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                newImage.Save(@"d:\NewImages1\" + oldfName + ".gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                string filesExit = sourceDirectory + "\\"+ oldfName + ".gif";
                if (!File.Exists(filesExit))
                {
                    newImage.Save(sourceDirectory + "\\" + oldfName + ".gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                }
                else
                {
                    itemToColor = "File already exist and was not overwritten:";
                    listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { listBox1.Items.Add("File already exist and was not overwritten: " + oldfName); }));

                }

            }

            if (newImage != null)
                newImage.Dispose();
        }
```

And i want to color in Red the item that Invoke:

```
listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { listBox1.Items.Add("File already exist and was not overwritten: " + oldfName); }));
```

I want to color in Red the text: File already exist and was not overwritten:

I changed in the designer the listbox1 draw mode to OwnderDrawFixed
And added draw item event.

In the draw item event i did:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Olive), e.Bounds);
            g.DrawString(itemToColor, e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
        }
```

itemToColor is global string in form1 i thought to color the text:

```
itemToColor = "File already exist and was not overwritten:";
listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { listBox1.Items.Add("File already exist and was not overwritten: " + oldfName); }));
```

But it's not working.

How can i color in red only the text in the Invoke ? File already exist and was not overwritten:
So it will color it only when it appears in the method if appears.

Comment: How is it _Not working_? If only one Item is supposed to be a different color you will need to know which; you may keep a list of inices or set the Tag.. If only a part of the Text should be in Red you will need to parse the parts and use DrawString calls for each part.. - You ca use the Parameters in e to know which Item you are drawing but the code must work for all Items! For the normal Items you can simply call `e.DrawDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any other indicator which Items are supposed to be in Red here is the low-tech way:

```
string itemToColor = "File already exist and was not overwritten.";
```

Using a ListView (as I had misread you) this would be the code:

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.Text != itemToColor ) e.DrawDefault = true;
   else
   {
     e.DrawBackground();
     // e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Olive), e.Bounds); // optional
     e.Graphics.DrawString(itemToColor, listView1.Font, 
                           Brushes.Red, new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
   }
}
```

Note: Depending on your needs you may also have to code the `DrawHeader` and `DrawSubItem` events!

As you are actually using a good old ListBox here is the same code for the `ListBox.DrawItem` event:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    SolidBrush brush = null;
    if (listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString() != itemToColor )
         brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
    else brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 
                          e.Font, brush, new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
}
```

Not sure if you really want to paint the Background in Olive.. If so you can easily change the cvode a little..

But a List of Items or ItemIndices or setting Tags may be more to your liking..

Comment: TaW e don't have Item property and not DrawDefault there is no e.Item and not e.DrawDefault

Comment: Whoops, you are right; I was coding for a `ListView`, which btw is almost always the better choice. Sorry about that, see the uzpdated answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working sample code

Remember to change the DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed and handle the DrawItem event.

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the DrawItem event of the listBox1 control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
private void listBox1_DrawItem( object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e )
{
   e.DrawBackground();
   Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    // draw the background color you want
    // mine is set to olive, change it to whatever you want
    g.FillRectangle( new SolidBrush( Color.Olive), e.Bounds );

    // draw the text of the list item, not doing this will only show
    // the background color
    // you will need to get the text of item to display
    g.DrawString( THE_LIST_ITEM_TEXT , e.Font, new SolidBrush( e.ForeColor ), new PointF( e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y) );

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Probably the missing  e.DrawFocusRectangle() is causing you the problem.